# How to insert a row which calculates the average of the rows above it?

Tags: r

I was looking to separate rows of data by Cue and adding a row which calculate averages per subject.  Here is an example:

Before:

```
    Cue ITI    a       b       c
1   0   16  0.82062 0.52185 0.27679
2   0   24  0.53894 0.49957 0.35767
3   4   22  0.26855 0.17487 0.22461
4   4   20  0.15106 0.48767 0.49072
5   7   18  0.11627 0.12604 0.2832
6   7   24  0.50201 0.14252 0.21454
7   12  16  0.27649 0.96008 0.42114
8   12  18  0.60852 0.21637 0.18799
9   22  20  0.32867 0.65308 0.29388
10  22  24  0.25726 0.37048 0.32379
```

After:

```
    Cue ITI    a       b       c
1   0   16  0.82062 0.52185 0.27679
2   0   24  0.53894 0.49957 0.35767
3           0.67978 0.51071 0.31723
4   4   22  0.26855 0.17487 0.22461
5   4   20  0.15106 0.48767 0.49072
6           0.209   0.331   0.357
7   7   18  0.11627 0.12604 0.2832
8   7   24  0.50201 0.14252 0.21454
9           0.309   0.134   0.248
10  12  16  0.27649 0.96008 0.42114
11  12  18  0.60852 0.21637 0.18799
12          0.442   0.588   0.304
13  22  20  0.32867 0.65308 0.29388
14  22  24  0.25726 0.37048 0.32379
15          0.292   0.511   0.308
```

So in the "after" example, line 3 is the average of lines 1 and 2 (line 6 is the average of lines 4 and 5, etc...).

Any help/information would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: this seems related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555851/adding-a-row-for-the-ratio-of-two-variables/48556600#48556600)

Answer (score 2):

You can use base r to do something like:

```
 Reduce(rbind,by(data,data[1],function(x)rbind(x,c(NA,NA,colMeans(x[-(1:2)])))))
   Cue ITI        a        b        c
1    0  16 0.820620 0.521850 0.276790
2    0  24 0.538940 0.499570 0.357670
3   NA  NA 0.679780 0.510710 0.317230
32   4  22 0.268550 0.174870 0.224610
4    4  20 0.151060 0.487670 0.490720
31  NA  NA 0.209805 0.331270 0.357665
5    7  18 0.116270 0.126040 0.283200
6    7  24 0.502010 0.142520 0.214540
33  NA  NA 0.309140 0.134280 0.248870
7   12  16 0.276490 0.960080 0.421140
8   12  18 0.608520 0.216370 0.187990
34  NA  NA 0.442505 0.588225 0.304565
9   22  20 0.328670 0.653080 0.293880
10  22  24 0.257260 0.370480 0.323790
35  NA  NA 0.292965 0.511780 0.308835
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea. Split the data frame, perform the analysis, and then combine them together.

```
DF_list <- split(DF, f = DF$Cue)

DF_list2 <- lapply(DF_list, function(x){
  df_temp <- as.data.frame(t(colMeans(x[, -c(1, 2)])))
  df_temp[, c("Cue", "ITI")] <- NA
  df <- rbind(x, df_temp)
  return(df)
})

DF2 <- do.call(rbind, DF_list2)
rownames(DF2) <- 1:nrow(DF2)
DF2
#    Cue ITI        a        b        c
# 1    0  16 0.820620 0.521850 0.276790
# 2    0  24 0.538940 0.499570 0.357670
# 3   NA  NA 0.679780 0.510710 0.317230
# 4    4  22 0.268550 0.174870 0.224610
# 5    4  20 0.151060 0.487670 0.490720
# 6   NA  NA 0.209805 0.331270 0.357665
# 7    7  18 0.116270 0.126040 0.283200
# 8    7  24 0.502010 0.142520 0.214540
# 9   NA  NA 0.309140 0.134280 0.248870
# 10  12  16 0.276490 0.960080 0.421140
# 11  12  18 0.608520 0.216370 0.187990
# 12  NA  NA 0.442505 0.588225 0.304565
# 13  22  20 0.328670 0.653080 0.293880
# 14  22  24 0.257260 0.370480 0.323790
# 15  NA  NA 0.292965 0.511780 0.308835
```

**DATA**

```
DF <- read.table(text = "    Cue ITI    a       b       c
1   0   16  0.82062 0.52185 0.27679
                 2   0   24  0.53894 0.49957 0.35767
                 3   4   22  0.26855 0.17487 0.22461
                 4   4   20  0.15106 0.48767 0.49072
                 5   7   18  0.11627 0.12604 0.2832
                 6   7   24  0.50201 0.14252 0.21454
                 7   12  16  0.27649 0.96008 0.42114
                 8   12  18  0.60852 0.21637 0.18799
                 9   22  20  0.32867 0.65308 0.29388
                 10  22  24  0.25726 0.37048 0.32379", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` approach, but if someone can offer some improvements I'd be keen to hear.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(df)

dt2 <- dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = Cue][,ITI := NA][]
data.table(rbind(dt, dt2))[order(Cue)][is.na(ITI), Cue := NA][]

> data.table(rbind(dt, dt2))[order(Cue)][is.na(ITI), Cue := NA][]
    Cue ITI        a        b        c
 1:   0  16 0.820620 0.521850 0.276790
 2:   0  24 0.538940 0.499570 0.357670
 3:  NA  NA 0.679780 0.510710 0.317230
 4:   4  22 0.268550 0.174870 0.224610
 5:   4  20 0.151060 0.487670 0.490720
 6:  NA  NA 0.209805 0.331270 0.357665
```

If you want to leave the Cue values as-is to confirm group, just drop the `[is.na(ITI), Cue := NA]` from the last line.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `group_by` and `summarise` from the `DPLYR` package to get a dataframe with the average values.  Then rbind the new data frame with the old one and sort by Cue:

```
df_averages <- df_orig >%>
  group_by(Cue) >%>
  summarise(ITI = NA, a = mean(a), b = mean(b), c = mean(c)) >%>
  ungroup()

df_all <- rbind(df_orig, df_averages)
```

Comment: I accidentally hit submit the first time.  Lets take it down a notch